# Internationalization in Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I want to use the internationalization for my GWT Application.

I read that i need a Languages.properties file in which I write for example ticketHomeSiteLabelDemnaechst="Activities due soon"

a class which i called Languages.java:

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages;

public interface Languages extends Messages{

    String ticketHomeSiteLabelDemnaechst();
}
```

applicationname.gwt.xml:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N'/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="de"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
```

And in the class where I want to use it:

```
final Languages language = GWT.create(Languages.class);
    labelDemnaechst.setText(Int.get(language.ticketHomeSiteLabelDemnaechst()));
```

When I do this:

I get this error: No source code is available for type Languages; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that Languages.java may be in the wrong package. Make sure it is in the `client` package, assuming that is where you keep your other gwt code (the EntryPoint, and whatever the last code snippet came from).

Comment: Thank you... It works.

Why does GWT need taht in the client package?

Comment: Any code that can be compiled into javascript code must be pointed out to the compiler as code that can be run on the client. This is done by specifying relative packages in your module file (the `<source path="client" />` tag, for example). You can add other packages other than `client`, just be sure that this package, and all packages referenced in that package, can be translated to JS.